# How to Show Menu on Click

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do you show an element after a user clicks on a separate element on the page using JQuery?

I have created a side menu with the following HTML:

```
<li id="navicon">
  <a href="" class="nav">
    <img src ="/assets/navicon-round.svg/" />
  </a>
</li>  
<ul class="side-categories">
    <li><a href="">CSS</li></a>
    <li><a href="">HTML</li></a>
    <li><a href="">JS/Jquery</li></a>
    <li><a href="">Miscellaneous</li></a>
</ul>
```

I set `.side-categories` to `display:none`

Now I want to be able show `.side-categories` when I click on `#nav`

I just started learning JQuery and this is what I have come up with. Yet, it is not working. I am hoping that someone can tell me what I have done wrong here.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#nav').on('click')event(function()) {
     event(showNavBar);
          $('.side-categories').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: You are also closing your <li> tags before you close your anchor (<a>) tags. In addition it doesn't make sense to have a <li> tag outside of a <ul> or <ol> as you have your "navicon>. You should also be using id's rather than classes for your navicon and side-categories

Comment: you have an extra closing parenthesis after your function in `event(function()) {` so it just finds an empty function that does nothing

Answer (score 3):

A good trick is to hide the sidebar menu using a class.

In your CSS:

```
.hide { 
   display: none;
}
```

And in your HTML: (the `<a>` can be removed if you want as jQuery can detect a click on any element)

```
<li id="navicon">
  <img class="nav" src ="/assets/navicon-round.svg/" />
</li>  
<ul class="side-categories hide">
  <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  <!-- More menu items -->
</ul>
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
$(function() {     
  $('.nav').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.side-categories').toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

This is a very simple way of allowing the user to hide the side menu again by clicking the same button - which is usually the expected behaviour.

An additional benefit is you keep your functions and styles seperate.

Comment: why not using `.hide()` and `.show()`? Saves you from adding extra css.

Comment: @giorgio, it's for seperation of concerns. For example in the future, you want to add an transition to the hide, it can done easily by adding one line of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1soh3t2/1/)**.

You should replace :

```
event(showNavBar);
```

By :

```
e.preventDefault();
```

**Full Code :**

```
 $(function() {     
    $('.nav').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.side-categories').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is HTML code :

```js
 $(function() {     
    $('.nav').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".side-categories").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <li id="navicon">
      <a href="" class="nav">
        <img style="height:40px;position:absolute;" src ="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
      </a>
    </li>  
    <ul class="side-categories" style="display:none">
        <li><a href="">CSS</li></a>
        <li><a href="">HTML</li></a>
        <li><a href="">JS/Jquery</li></a>
        <li><a href="">Miscellaneous</li></a>
    </ul>
```

for Live Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/4zuL5bmt/

Answer (score -1):

**Html:**

```
<li id="navicon">
  <a href="" class="nav">
    <img src ="/assets/navicon-round.svg/" />
  </a>
</li>  
<ul class="side-categories" style="display:none">
    <li><a href="">CSS</li></a>
    <li><a href="">HTML</li></a>
    <li><a href="">JS/Jquery</li></a>
    <li><a href="">Miscellaneous</li></a>
</ul>
```

**Replace Your JQuery**

```
  $(function() {     
        $('#navicon').click(function() {  // Change # instead of .
        $(".side-categories").show();
      });
   });
```

**OR**

```
 $(function() {     
   $('#navicon').on('click',function() {
      $(".side-categories").show();
   });
 });
```

Hope it works.....